# Deploy Laravel 5.1 on a cloud hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I developed my laravel application on wamp. I am finally done and rent a cloud hosting server with CPanel interface. I uploaded all my files on public html and tried going to the site. It's supposed to go to login page but not working.

I used to deploy classic html file, this is the first time I'm deploying a PHP laravel site. I've successfully imported my MySQL database so it's ready. I'm just clueless of the configuration etc.

Comment: Any information on what happens is also usefull. Like are you getting a error message? are there mesages in the logs? 

Possible things that you need to check:

- .env config file and values
- is the /storage folder writable
- is the docroot directed toward /public
- is php installed and configured

Comment: Does your php/Laravel log contain anything?

Comment: You should also specify where you are hosting this, like is it on digitalocean and etc. Because laravel needs to be hosted on a linux server. DigitalOcean would be a good choice.

Comment: well, right now looks like my main page only has directory displaying laravel folders such as app, resources, etc. I just can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: looks like your virtual host is pointing to the project root, not the public directory. This is a common issue with cpanel based hosts. You need to go to your domains section on the cpanel and change the root to /public_html/public or something like that. A google search "cpanel change domain root directory" will help you

Comment: Please don't deploy it to Digitalocean. As far as I can see, your expertise is not quite far enough to install all the needed software on a bare linux machine. For example: you will need a webserver (Nginx, Apache), you need php5-fpm or hvm if you are using Nginx. Besides that, you need to define config files for your virtualhosts. If you are all familiar with these aforementioned subjects, I can send you a Nginx config, which I use myself. For a quickstart, try to use Laravel Forge ($10,- a month). If you want to configure it yourself go for Digitalocean ($5,-).

Comment: This is not a linux machine, it's a CPanel based. I dont think it is linux.

Comment: CPanel based machines are on shared hosts. My solution should work as I myself use the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll walk you through the steps. Since you mentioned about `public_html` folder, I assume that this solution will work for you. Please follow the steps and change `myapp` to whatever your app name is.

- Copy your project's `public` folder into `public_html` folder and rename it (Say `myapp_public`)
- You will see a `.htaccess` file in `public_html` folder. Edit the contents of that file as follows:

  `RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^myapp_public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myapp_public/$1 [L]`
- Copy other folders in the root directory inside another directory say `myapp`
- Now the final thing that you need to do is, to edit `index.php` file at the path `public_html/myapp_public/index.php` (if you followed the steps I wrote above). Change `require` statement as follows

Change `require` statement as follows:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../myapp/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

Change `$app` variable as follows:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../myapp/bootstrap/app.php';
```

And this should do it. Drawing out the simple directory structure for easiness.

```
~
|__ myapp
|     |____ .env
|     |____ app
|     |____ artisan
|     |____ .........so on
|
|__ public_html
          |_____ .htaccess (this is the file to edit)
          |_____ myapp_public
                     |________ .htaccess
                     |________ index.php (this is the file to edit)
                     |________ robots.txt ...... so on
```

I will explain in detail if you do not understand what is happening here.

**EDIT**

Make sure that you have installed `composer` via `cURL` as `apt-get` wont work on shared hosts. Once done, run `composer install` from your project's root directory i.e. `myapp` if you followed above steps.

Comment: I'm following your advice but I don't see any .htaccess file in public_html folder.

Comment: it's still not working. first off, I assume .htaccess under public_html was either there or automatically generated but it was not. So I copied .htaccess from my myapp_public to public_html directory. still it's not working

Comment: There should be. I haven't seen any paid shared hosting without that file in public_html. You should probably consider speaking to the service provider

Comment: I tried copying the index.php to the public_html folder and I get server error 500. Is it probably because I changed my application name with composer to another name? Or is it probably has something to do with the  file permission?

Comment: Try having a small application running first. Maybe the initial laravel page. If you get a 500, what does the error log say?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add more information regarding composer installation

Comment: Vishal, I have composer on my desktop, but how do you modify anything if the folder myapp is in another server not a localhost.

Comment: use SSH login to your shared host

Comment: I looked at the error log and it says this
[09-Dec-2015 21:48:49 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/losmrsco/public_html/amri_public/index.php on line 50

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, Vishal's answer really helped, but I needed to change my PHP version setting to 5.5 or higher, after looking at the error log and googling the error. Thanks again Vishal. I still have problems with database connection but I think I can handle it from here.

Comment: yet, I got a downvote on my answer :) 
Glad I could help.