# Laravel wsod (white screen of death) on godaddy hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, wsod

I'm developing a laravel 5.1 application which is working absolutely fine on my localhost. But when I deploy it to GoDaddy's shared hosting, it gives a blank white page on opening the domain.

I have followed this tutorial to upload to the server.
http://www.nickmarriotti.com/blog/deploying-laravel-5-project-to-godaddy

How can I resolve this error problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look at my answer on this. 
Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174779/deploy-laravel-5-1-on-a-cloud-hosting/34175815#34175815

Comment: What are your logs showing? Both the Laravel log and your server logs.

Comment: Also, try these steps: `php artisan cache:clear`, then `chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap`, and then `composer dump-autoload`. I can see you have already done the storage folder, however you also need to do the bootstrap folder in most cases also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check the file permissions. Generally this issue comes when file permissions are not as it should be. Better call the GoDaddy customer care and they will run a quick check and will tell you if there is any problem with file permissions.

Also, GoDaddy Server, I mean CPanel by default supports a lower PHP Version. Where as New versions of laravel requires PHP >= 5.5.9. Kindly tell GoDaddy guys to upgrade your Server PHP version.

Follow these two steps and you should be fine.

Comment: Upgraded the PHP version. Now it is working great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most common installation errors caused by invalid permissions. Please login via ssh to your server and run this command to fix it.

```
chmod -R 777 LARAVEL/storage
```

Here `LARAVEL` is the path to your laravel installation in `Laravel 5.*`, while as for `Laravel 4.*`, `LARAVEL` will be `path/to/laravel/app`, as `storage` resides inside `app` directory in `Laravel 4.*` installations.

Comment: Show the output of LARAVEL/storage/logs/laravel.log