# Laravel 5 shared hosting issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

please, I am trying to host Laravel 5 on a shared hosting.

When I access www.example.com/my_app_name, the page loaded correctly.
However, subfolders return 404 error. e.g. www.example.com/my_app_name/any_sub_folder or www.example.com/my_app_name/auth/login all return a 404 error.

```
shared_hosting_root
|--other_folders (not accessible via web domain)

|--applications  (not accessible via web domain)

|--my_app_name
|--app
  |--GoPublic.php <--I created this
|--bootstrap
|--config
|--database
|--public <--copied content to public_html
  |--assets
  |--index.php
|--resources
|--storage
|--tests
|--vendor

|--public_html
|--my_app_name
|--assets
|--index.php <-- I pointed here
```

I created a new file: shared_hosting_root\applications\my_app_name\app\GoPublic.php

```
<?php namespace App;

class GoPublic extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
{
 /**
 * Get the path to the public / web directory.
 *
 * @return string
 */
 public function publicPath()
 {
 return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../../public_html/my_app_name';
 }
}
```

I edited bootstrap\app.php like so:

```
<?php

/* -- remove/comment this original code
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
 realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
-- until here */

/* -- add this new code -- */
$app = new App\GoPublic(
 realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

I edited public\index.php like so:
I changed this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../../applications/my_app_name/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and also changed this:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../applications/my_app_name/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I then copied the content inside applications\my_app_name\public into public_html\my_app_name.

I followed the steps highlighted in this tutorial: http://blog.kongnir.com/2015/09/25/setting-up-laravel-5-on-shared-hosting-server/

**The problem again:**

I can access *www.example.com/my_app_name*.

But I get a **404 error** on *www.example.com/my_app_name/any_sub_folder* or even a login redirect *www.example.com/myapp_name/auth/login*

What am I doing wrong? Help, please.
Thank you.

**Update**
www.example.com/my_app_name/sub_folder returns 500 internal server error
My .htaccess file in public_html directory:

```
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 

# Change example.com to your domain name
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?schoolsmart.com.ng$ 

# Change your_app_name to the subfolder name
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wbs/ 

# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

# Change your_app_name to the subfolder name
# Change example.com to your domain name
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wbs/$1 
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?schoolsmart.com.ng$ 
# RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wbs/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wbs
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wbs/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Are you getting anything here `example.com/my_app_name/index.php/any_sub_folder` ?

Comment: I've answered this before. Please follow the steps here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34175815/4159199

Comment: Thanks @VishalSh I followed the steps in your link and I get a 503 error for www.example.com/my_app_name/any_subfolder.

However, ww.example.com/my_app_name/index.php/any_sub_folder

Please, lookup my updated question for my .htaccess code.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you get when you access: `example.com/my_app_name/index.php/any_sub_folder` ?

Comment: When I try to access `example.com/my_app_name/index.php/any_sub_folder`  I get 

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\View\Expression' not found in /home/schoolsm/applications/wbs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 215`.

Please, help

Answer (score 0):

For me chmoding the bootstrap, storage and yajra folder which is under vendor directory to 775, as suggested in the official laravel documentation, did the trick.